# Is there a way to profile MS access database to find out what SQL run against it?

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to profile MS access database to find out what SQL run against it?

Comment: Can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: If you're accessing it with ODBC, you can turn on ODBC logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do some searching on Jet ShowPlan.    I haven't used it myself so I don't have any URLs to recommend.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, even though it doesn't show the exact SQL, but it does display the table names and conditions.